# SQL Server CE Select count of employee posts every year between 2 dates

Tags: calendar, sql-server-ce, gaps-and-islands

I have an `Employees` table with columns `ID, PostID, StartDate, EndDate`.

Sample Data

```
ID   PostID  StartDate   EndDate
----------------------------------------
1    1       2005/15/08   null      <---Null is still employed
2    2       2006/02/04  2006/08/06
3    1       2004/03/07  9999/12/31 <--- Can also be still Employed
4    2       2008/04/01   null
```

Correct result would be

```
Year Post Total
2004 1    1
2005 1    2
2006 1    2
2006 2    1
2007 1    2
2007 2    0
2008 1    2
2008 2    1
```

Note that in 2007 `EmployeeID = 2 PostID = 2` has been terminated (`Endate = 2006/08/06`)

Want to return sum of specific PostID's

I used

```
SUM(CASE WHEN PostID=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) HPMP, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN PostID=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) HPN,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN PostID=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) HPMW
```

to get specific Posts

The problem is that I need to group this for each YEAR between say 1990 and 2012

**Important:** I am using SQL Server CE and cannot use scripts or stored procedures.

Must be a select grouped by statement.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll want a table of years. Some DBMSs have ways to create these on the fly. Assuming a Years Table with a Year Column, and one row per year then the following should work:

```
Select
  y.Year,
  e.PostID,
  Count(*) As Total
From
  Years y
    Inner Join
  Employees e
    On y.Year >= Year(e.StartDate) And (y.Year <= Year(e.EndDate) Or e.EndDate Is Null)
Group By
  y.Year,
  e.PostID
Order By
  1, 2
```

You can add a where clause to restrict the year range. e.g. Where y.Year >= Year(GetDate()) - 5 And y.Year <= Year(GetDate())

If you want to include the zeros too:

```
Select
    y.Year,
    p.PostID,
    Count(e.ID) As Total
From
    Years y
        Cross Join
    (Select Distinct PostID From Employees) p
        Left Outer Join
    Employees e
        On 
            y.Year >= Year(e.StartDate) And 
            (y.Year <= Year(e.EndDate) Or e.EndDate Is Null) And
            p.PostID = e.PostID
Group By
    y.Year,
    p.PostID
Order By
    1, 2
```

If you have a Posts table, you'd use this instead of the select distinct bit

Comment: Thanks Laurence. That was very Helpful. Pity I have to have a Year Table.

Comment: You can generate them on the fly with CTEs, but I'm not sure if SQL CE has them. e.g. http://aaronakinsql.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/recursive-common-table-expressions-part-2/. Also SQL server has an undocumented table `master..spt_values` that has the numbers from 0 to 2047 that you could use. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156493/how-to-create-a-list-of-dates-from-a-daterange-without-using-a-cte. Again I'm not sure if CE has it.