# How to create a list of dates from a daterange without using a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

The following link explains how to turn a date range into a list of dates.
I used this approach and it works fine but the query is not performing (I used Maxrecursion 0 to unlimit).

http://blog.justinstolle.com/sql-turn-a-date-range-into-a-list-of-dates/

Is there any other solution to get this done? (using subquery or declare table?)

Comment: Actually not but it is not performing.

Comment: Please check the query posted.

Comment: I have 10000 records. Is it fast also?

Comment: Oeps, I have 86896 records and it takes 32 seconds. That why i not prefer CTE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
declare @datestart date = '2012-1-1',   @dateend date = '2012-10-31'

declare @days int = datediff(d,@datestart,@dateend)

select
    dateadd(d, number, @datestart)
from master..spt_values 
where type='p'
    and number<=@days
```

If your date range is more than 2047 days, you can extend it by self joining the table - the below will allow you up to 27 years..

```
select
    dateadd(d, v1.number+v2.number*2048, @datestart)
from master..spt_values v1
    cross join (select number from master..spt_values where number<5 and type='p') v2       
where type='p'
    and (v1.number+v2.number*2048)<=@days
```

Comment: Why are you using number from the master database?

Comment: I don't have an idea how to self joining the table. Can you please provide the approach with the self joining?

Comment: I actually meant a self joining whithout using the master database.

Comment: If you can't use master, if you're going to be repeating this query, then i'd advise creating a dates table with all forseeable dates in it as a one off task.

Answer (score -1):

This is the same query in the link with a minor modification (using CTE). Please check:

```
DECLARE @dateranges TABLE (range_id VARCHAR(2), date_begin DATETIME, date_end DATETIME)
INSERT @dateranges SELECT 'A', '2010-01-01', '2010-01-03'
INSERT @dateranges SELECT 'B', '2008-02-27', '2008-03-01'
INSERT @dateranges SELECT 'C', '2010-04-26', '2010-04-26'
INSERT @dateranges SELECT 'D', '2000-02-01', '2001-02-05'

;WITH cte (id, d)
AS (SELECT tbl.range_id AS id, tbl.date_begin AS d
    FROM @dateranges tbl
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, tbl.date_begin, tbl.date_end) >0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tbl.range_id AS id, DATEADD(DAY, 1, cte.d) AS d
    FROM cte INNER JOIN @dateranges tbl
    ON cte.id = tbl.range_id
    WHERE cte.d < tbl.date_end)
SELECT id AS range_id, d AS date_within_range FROM cte
ORDER BY id, d
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```