# Nest With clause inside a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a recursive query using Common Table Expressions which gets the range of dates between a start and end date

```
WITH T(date) AS (
SELECT @StartDate UNION ALL
SELECT DateAdd(day,1,T.date)   FROM T WHERE datediff(dd,T.date , @EndDate)>0 )
SELECT date FROM T OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767))
```

Is there any way for me to nest this within another select statement without creating a temporary table?

I'm looking for a statement like so

```
select * from (WITH T(date) AS (
    SELECT @StartDate UNION ALL
    SELECT DateAdd(day,1,T.date)   FROM T WHERE datediff(dd,T.date , @EndDate)>0 )
    SELECT date FROM T OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)))
join 
    (select * from SomeTable where MyDate between @StartDate and @EndDate)
on //Some condition
```

I've tried this out in SQL Server and there is an

> Incorrect Syntax near WITH

error being thrown.

By definition, CTE only exists within the scope of the query. So, is it necessary that a Temporary table is necessary to store the results of the CTE or can the above scenario also work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use multiple CTEs by separating them with a comma, e.g:

```
WITH T(date) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDate 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateAdd(day,1,T.date)  
    FROM T
    WHERE datediff(dd,T.date , @EndDate)>0 

), T2 AS
(
    SELECT date 
    FROM T 
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
)
select * from t2
join 
    (select * from SomeTable where MyDate between @StartDate and @EndDate)
on //Some condition
```

For what it's worth though, using a recursive CTE to generate a list of dates is not the best way. The best way is to have a [static calendar table](http://blog.jontav.com/post/9380766884/calendar-tables-are-incredibly-useful-in-sql), failing this you can generate a set of dates on the fly as follows:

```
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @StartDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;
```

This will be more efficient than looping through dates. For more information see:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 3](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

Comment: Everything I wanted and more. Thanks...:-)

Answer (score 0):

Create the CTE first, then select from it.

```
;WITH T(date) AS (
    SELECT @StartDate UNION ALL
    SELECT DateAdd(day,1,T.date)   FROM T WHERE datediff(dd,T.date , @EndDate)>0 
)
select * from T
join 
    (select * from SomeTable where MyDate between @StartDate and @EndDate) v
on //Some condition
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

If you're trying to create a date range, this may help : [How to create a list of dates from a daterange without using a CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156493/how-to-create-a-list-of-dates-from-a-daterange-without-using-a-cte)